# What if more than one answers are accptable?

Tags: discussion

We have one answer to be marked as Accepted now. In many cases there are two or more answers can be acceptable.

Suppose a problem that can be solved either by the code-solution "A" or by the code-solution "B" or by the plugin-solution "C" etc.

In that case it'd not be justified for an asker to accept only a single answer and give 15 reputation plus to his/her (the solution provider) profile. In that particular scenario there should have the privilege to accept more than one answer. For me only an upvote isn't justified enough to the solution-providers.

But to refrain from miss-use we can make it available after certain reputation, i.e. 100 or 200 etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see the need for multiple accepted answers.

There are rarely multiple equal quality answers. *Something* sets them apart. The asker can pick the one actually used or best fitted and upvote anything else, or not as appropriate.

Allowing multiple accepted answers really just waters down the significance of the accepted answer. You may as well just remove it altogether and depend only on the voting.

Allowing multiple accepted answers would probably encourage less well considered acceptance of answers. If you can only pick one, you will think about it more than if you can just accept two or three or four or whatever. As is, you can only pick one accepted answer and changing your mind costs rep, if I remember right.

I like the system as is.

Comment: Nicely concluded: *"Allowing multiple accepted answers would probably encourage less well considered acceptance of answers."*. Thanks, got it.